# Calculate startOffset to align the middle of the text to the top of a circle in SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I want to align the middle of the text with the top of a circle. I'm using <path> and <textpath> to render the text along the circular path in the svg. The *startOffset* attribute helps to achieve it but I want to calculate it in js. Here is the svg code:

```
<svg id="svg" width="500" height="500">
<defs><path d="M 180 200
    m -100, 0
    a 100,100 0 1,1 200,0
    a 100,100 0 1,1 -200,0
    " id="pathSlf6u6uz93">
    </path>
</defs>
<text x="50" y="50">
<textPath xlink:href="#pathSlf6u6uz93">Curved text testing</textPath>
</text>
<path d="M 180 200
    m -100, 0
    a 100,100 0 1,1 200,0
    a 100,100 0 1,1 -200,0
    " style="" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke="#000000">
</path>
</svg>
```

Here is the solution using startOffset. The only issue is that I don't know how to calculate.

```html
<svg id="svg" width="500" height="500">
<defs><path d="M 180 200
    m -100, 0
    a 100,100 0 1,1 200,0
    a 100,100 0 1,1 -200,0
    " id="pathSlf6u6uz93">
    </path>
</defs>
<text x="50" y="50">
<textPath xlink:href="#pathSlf6u6uz93" startOffset="45">Curved text testing</textPath>
</text>
<path d="M 180 200
    m -100, 0
    a 100,100 0 1,1 200,0
    a 100,100 0 1,1 -200,0
    " style="" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke="#000000">
</path>
</svg>
```

My end goal is to achieve text curve like in canva.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the following example I've marked the begining of the path with a small circle.

I gather that you need to center the text around the point at 25% of the path length.

In order to do this I've temoved the x and y attributes of the text and set the `startOffset="25%"`. Also I use `text-anchor="middle"`. This is centering the text around the desired point. No need of JS. You can now change the radius of the circle and the text will stay centered where you need it to be.

```
d="M 180 200
        m -R, 0
        a R,R 0 1,1 200,0
        a R,R 0 1,1 -200,0"
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="500" height="500">
<defs><path d="M 180 200
    m -100, 0
    a 100,100 0 1,1 200,0
    a 100,100 0 1,1 -200,0
    " id="pathSlf6u6uz93">
    </path>
</defs>
<text>
<textPath xlink:href="#pathSlf6u6uz93" startOffset="25%" text-anchor="middle">Curved text testing</textPath>
</text>
<use href="#pathSlf6u6uz93"
     style="" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke="#000000">
</use>
<circle cx="80" cy="200" r="3" />
</svg>
```

Please observe that I'm using a `<use>` element instead of redrawing the path.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The solution works perfectly for the above text and circle radius. However, when I used a longer text and a smaller radius, the text was clipped.

Comment: Add more arc segments then.

Comment: @NishalGurung are you wanting a completely general solution - e.g. when the text is so long it might wrap twice around the circle - or are there any constraints?

Comment: I also need to calculate constraint so that the circle's perimeter does not become smaller than the text.

Comment: perimeter = 2πr textLength=text.getComputedTextLength() compare the two.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks! When the curvature is 10, we can implement the formula to calculate the minimum value of the radius i.e. r  = textlength/2π. But how can we calculate the radius if the curvature value is less than 10 or greater than 0 like in the gif above ?

Comment: Sounds like you need a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Addendum to Enxaneta his answer, you can set `pathLength` on the `<path>` and position with relative notation

```html
<svg id="svg" width="500" height="500">
<defs>
  <path id="p1" pathLength="4" d="M180 100m-100,0a100,100 0 1,1 200,0a100,100 0 1,1-200,0"/>
</defs>
<text>
<textPath href="#p1" startOffset="2" text-anchor="middle">Curved text testing</textPath>
</text>
<use href="#p1" fill="pink" stroke="#000000" />
<circle cx="80" cy="200" r="3" />
</svg>
```